# How do I extract values from a JSON array in MariaDB or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

### Situation

I have a table in a MariaDB database. This table has a **LONGTEXT** column which is used to store a **JSON array** (read more about this topic in [MariaDB JSON Data Type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/)).

### Question

I would like to extract values from the JSON array, based on a certain key. How do I achieve this with MariaDB (or MySQL)?

### Example

Here's the simplified table `thing` (just for demo purposes):

| id | thing_name | examples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | fruit | `[{"color": "green","title": "Apple"},{"color": "orange","title": "Orange"},{"color": "yellow","title": "Banana"}]` |
| 1 | car | `[{"color": "silver","title": "VW"},{"color": "black","title": "Bentley"},{"color": "blue","title": "Tesla"}]` |

**My goal is to extract all `title` values from the JSON array.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/) for this task (works for both MariaDB and MySQL). This function also supports **wildcards**, as described in the docs:

> Paths can contain * or ** wildcards

Depending on whether you have multiple levels of data (e.g. single document vs array), either a single or double asterisk wildcard should be used:

```sql
JSON_EXTRACT(json,'$**.key')
```

`json` is a valid JSON document (e.g. a column), `key` is the lookup key used.

### For your example

In order to find all `title` values in your JSON array, use the following query:

```sql
SELECT id, thing_name, JSON_EXTRACT(examples, '$**.title') as examples_titles FROM thing
```

| id | thing_name | examples_titles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | fruit | `["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]` |
| 1 | car | `["VW", "Bentley", "Tesla"]` |

Comment: It takes seconds to answer your own question? 0_0

Comment: And all of this is available in the manual ?

Comment: @the_coding_cat You can ask questions on Stack Overflow in [Q&A style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.90169755.1022439125.1652858903-73467118.1643011997), as they call it (i.e. already provide the answer when formulating the question). It's intended for situations where you've found a solution for your problem already and want to share this finding with the world. Or ideally, even find a better solution from other answers in the future. :)

Comment: Oh... I see. Okay, I'm just flabbergasted. Anyways as long as it will help the future readers and as long as the answer is really helpful, then there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: The solution does not match the task, it seems. The task "extract all title values from the JSON array" should match "one value per output row" whereas you obtain an array with title values, i.e. one output row for source row.