# Extracting value from a JSON array in a MariaDB table column

Tags: json, mariadb, json-extract

Would appreciate if you can help a mariaDB newbie with this.

I have a mariaDB database table called 'brand' with data as below.

Datatypes are VARCHAR and JSON.

```
name varchar(255) NOT NULL
```

```
sold longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL CHECK (json_valid('sold'))
```

| name | sold |
| --- | --- |
| Test | `[{"id":"0","name":"0","count":5000},{"id":"1","name":"1","count":5000}]` |
| Test2 | `[{"id":"0","name":"0","count":10000},{"id":"1","name":"1","count":10000}]` |
| Test3 | `[{"id":"0","name":"0","count":15000},{"id":"1","name":"1","count":35000}]` |
| Test4 | `[{"id":"0","name":"0","count":700},{"id":"1","name":"1","count":600}]` |

When I execute the query:

```
SELECT name, JSON_EXTRACT(sold, '$[*].count') as cnt FROM brands;
```

```
SELECT name, JSON_EXTRACT(sold, '$**.count') as cnt FROM brands;
```

I get the below output

| name | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| Test | `[5000, 5000]` |
| Test2 | 10000 |
| Test3 | 15000 |
| Test4 | 700 |

I was expecting output as below

| name | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| Test | `[5000, 5000]` |
| Test2 | `[10000, 10000]` |
| Test3 | `[15000, 35000]` |
| Test4 | `[700, 600]` |

Can you please help me correct the error?

1. I have searched the mariaDB documentation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/ but not able to find a solution yet.
2. I also looked at this post: [How do I extract values from a JSON array in MariaDB or MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72285515/how-do-i-extract-values-from-a-json-array-in-mariadb-or-mysql) and I am implementing same SQL...

Thank you!

**Update: 25 Jan**

Ticket submitted to JIRA mariadb and fixed [here](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/b915b96f7224e04d4509f1e4c6a4193347715097)

Comment: I see no errors with your setup. Please see [this test fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kSQw2Xaz). Are these your exact queries? What's your MariaDB version? Also, be sure to check if there are no misspellings for the `count` keys for the data you're not getting.

Comment: Version I am using is 10.10.2-MariaDB. Thank you for the link. When I use version 10.9 in the fiddle link, it gives me the same 'wrong' output. When I use version 10.8 and lower, it gives me the expected output. Any idea why?

Comment: Check [existing bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22json_extract%22%20and%20(status!%3DClosed%20or%20fixVersion%20%3D10.11.2)) and if not there, create a new one please.

Comment: I have submitted a new bug.